# iphone 4S not playing voice memo

Tags: iphone

Cannot play a voice memo I recorded earlier this week. It appears to be there but when I hit the arrow to play, nothing happens. When I sync my phone up to my pc only 2 of the voice memos show up yet my phone tells me there are 4. I can play 3 of the 4 but no this one. Please advise.

Answer (score 1):

Your voice memo is being played through the earpiece speaker. You can listen to it, just tap play and put your iPhone up to your ear, as if you were taking a phone call.

To play through the loud speaker, like almost everything else, tap the speaker icon in the top right, it should turn blue. Now play your voice memo like you normally would and it will play through the loud speaker, as opposed to the earpiece speaker. If it doesn't, ensure that the silence switch on the left side of your iPhone is up and that the volume is on.